# Unresolved reference: test gradle kotlin dsl error

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've parent gradle project with bunch of subprojects.

I would like to put common config under subprojects.

Below is my configuration file -

```kotlin
allprojects {
group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        val implementation by configurations
        val testImplementation by configurations
        implementation("io.netty:netty-all:4.1.96.Final")
        implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.7")
        testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))
        testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    }

    tasks.test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

The configuration `tasks.test { useJUnitPlatform() }` outside subprojects is working fine.

But when I move inside `subprojects`  module I'm getting error `Unresolved reference: test`.

How can I fix this error?